# Convergence, Divergence and Summability of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

If f(x) is an infinitely differentiable function at x=0 and $f^{(n)}(0)$ is the nth derivative of the function f at zero, then does the series below converge or diverge?

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f^{(n+1)}(0)-f^{(n)}(0)$

For what kind of functions does the series converge? For what kind of functions that will make the above a divergent series, there is a known summation method?

Comment: Certainly for polynomials we have convergence. Also analytic functions whose power series $\sum a_kx^k$ satisfy $\sum \left(a_{k+1}(k+1)!-a_{k}k!\right)<\infty $

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sequence of the partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n+1)}(0)-f^{(n)}(0)$
is 
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n f^{(k+1)}(0)-f^{(k)}(0)=f^{(n+1)}(0)-f^{(0)}(0).
$$
Thus summability of the series is equivalent to the convergence of the sequence $f^{(n)}(0)$.

Take for example $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{ax}$, which is $C^\infty$ in $\mathbb R$. Then
$$
f^{(n)}(0)=a^n.
$$
This tends to $0$ is $|a|<1$, is equal to $1$ if $a=1$, does not tend anywhere if $a=-1$, tends to infinity if $a>1$.

In general, we can not say what the series does.

Comment: I think, on the rightmost expression in the $s_n$-formula, we should have $f^{(0)}(0)$ instead of  $f^{(n)}(0)$ ? (The sum is telescoping such that all intermediate elements vanish)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Correct. Thanks.

Comment: +1. A nice phrase in this context is `telescoping series`.